# Get three highest values from the array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to get three highes values from my array, but it should be sorted properly by keys also.

I have this code:

```
<?php
$a = array(130, 1805, 1337);
arsort($a);
print_r($a);
?>
```

The output of the above is following:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1805
    [2] => 1337
    [0] => 130
)
```

Its working fine, but I want it additionaly to sort its keys from the highest to the lowest value.

Example:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 1805
    [1] => 1337
    [0] => 130
)
```

To be clear: I want it be to sorted by the keys: array key number 2 will be always used for the *highest* value, array key number 0 will be always used for the *lowest* value.

How can I do that?

*/let me know if you don't understand something.*

Comment: Did any of the answers here correctly sorted by value ***and* key**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
rsort($array);
$top3 = array_reverse(array_slice($array, 0, 3));
```

Comment: Just a note for @Cyclone, if you use `array_slice` as @deceze pointed out, it will only return the top 3 values. If you want to affect _all_ values, leave it out.

Comment: @deceze Thank you ! :-) That was what I've looking for.

Comment: @deceze I wouldn't hold your breath, it's was probably more of an 'elevation through collateral downvoting' strategy... So sad

Comment: Why not `$top3 = array_slice($array, -3);`?

Comment: @Alix True, that's a nice solution as well when combined with sorting the other way.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`array_reverse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) for this.

```
<?php
$a = array(130, 1805, 1337);
arsort($a);
print_r(array_reverse($a));
?>
```

Easily accessed by `$a[0]`, `$a[1]`, `$[2]` to get your highest values.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array(130, 1805, 1337);
arsort($a);
array_reverse($a);
```

Would produce:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 1807
    [1] => 1337
    [0] => 130
)
```

You can find out more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php).

Comment: Just a note: `array_reverse()` doesn't change the original array, it returns the reversed array, so you have to catch it in a variable or it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
<?php
$a = array(130, 1805, 1337); 
arsort($a);
$a = array_reverse($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the output you described with any of the answers already posted (tested via IDEOne.com).

---

Here is my solution ([demo](http://ideone.com/DthmE)):

```
$a = array(130, 1805, 1337);

$keys = array_keys($a); rsort($keys, SORT_NUMERIC);
$values = array_values($a); rsort($values, SORT_NUMERIC);

$a = array_combine(array_slice($keys, 0, 3), array_slice($values, 0, 3));

print_r($a);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 1805
    [1] => 1337
    [0] => 130
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$array = array(130, 1805, 1337);
sort($array);
for ($i=0; $i <= count($array)-1; $i++)

      $arr[]=$array[$i];
      print_r($arr);

?>
```