# How to get rows with highest values from a list of values

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo

So basically I have an auction log SQL table which shows what bets were made from the start to the final bet. They just go in a row from the starting bet to the winning one. So it looks something like this:

150, 200, 250, 300, **350**, 150, 200, **250**, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, **400** and so on.

I want to grab all the winning bets (the highest ones in a row) from the log and I cant get my head around how to do it.

Does anyone have any idea for the best way to accomplish this with PDO/PHP?

I naturally thought of foreach loops but couldn't really figure out the best way to approach it.
I also tried making it into an array but didn't have success there.

```
$query = $pdo_2->prepare("SELECT `bet` FROM `auction_log` ORDER by `id` DESC");
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row){
    $madebet = $row['bet'];
    echo $madebet; echo '<br>';
}
```

That just shows every bet that was made. I couldn't figure out how to filter out the ones I don't need.

Edit. Table structure:

```
INSERT INTO `auction_log`(`id`, `bet`, `user`, `date`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4])


`id` is AUTO_INCREMENT
`bet` float(9,2) - price/currency of a bet
`user` text - name of user who made the bet
`date` datetime - time of bet
```

Comment: Please read about [providing a minimal, reproducible example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). If you share an example of your database, it is likely we can suggest a way that will solve this through the query itself.

Comment: Are you storing multiple bid in a single row as comma separated value? If yes, its real bad practice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get three highest values from the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935712/get-three-highest-values-from-the-array)

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for the replies!  I share the table structure. Hopefully that's what you meant.

Comment: Table structure is itself incorrect, needs to be something like this: `id is AUTO_INCREMENT
bet_price float(9,2) - price/currency of a bet
bet_id - id of a bet
user_id id - id of user who made the bet
date datetime - time of bet`

Comment: well, yeah. It could've been made much easier if I kept bets' ids. But that's how it is now and so I'm wondering if there's a way to do what I need or not.

Comment: You still haven't properly explained what you need. Please read the MRE link thoroughly and provide a proper example. You only gave us bits of information, we still have to guess the remainder. What exactly are you looking for? How is the winning bid determined?

Comment: @Dosyk  there is no way to find out how many bid prices added in your table for a particular bid. So it's impossible to get highest price for each bid

Comment: Sorry! Okay, will do. I just thought it's easy to understand but I guess it's probably easy for me cause I know how it works. So, forgive. It's very simple actually. It's just a log file. Every time a bet is made, it adds a bid into the log, values just go one after the other. So if Roger bets 200, insert happens: 200, roger, date. then, say James bets 250, another insert but with James's 250. When the auction ends nothing is written in until a new auction starts, so new values are added again just like before. Nothing gets deleted from log, just more and more values from new auctions.

Comment: Alive 2 Die, got it! Okay, well was just wondering if it was possible to compare the numbers in a row or something. like if number 350 is less then the next one (150) then write it into a winning bet. Or something like that. But okay, got it . Thanks

Comment: @Dosyk  as I said until you come to know how many prices applied for one bid you cannot found out highest among them. Your current table not able to tell that first 5 bid prices related to bid1,next 3 related to bid2, next 7 related to bid3.... I hope you are able to understand what I am trying to say

Comment: @Dosyk  if it's a log file then why you said it's a table?

Comment: It's okay guys. Yes, I understand what you mean. I'll just create a separate table for that. Thanks for your time and have a great productive day/night.